# How to shorten a conditional expression with Android Databinding

Tags: android-layout, android-databinding

I just want to make the following snippet shorter and more readable.

```
<LinearLayout android:visibility="@{ viewModel.prediction.intent == PredictionIntentType.MEETING_FOLLOWUP || (viewModel.prediction.intent == PredictionIntentType.FOLLOWUP &amp;&amp; !viewModel.isMeetingViewGroupShown) || (viewModel.prediction.intent == PredictionIntentType.MEETING &amp;&amp; viewModel.isMeetingViewGroupShown) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE }" />
```

When I do it multiline (see below) it won't compile

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:visibility="@{ viewModel.prediction.intent == PredictionIntentType.MEETING_FOLLOWUP 
    || (viewModel.prediction.intent == PredictionIntentType.FOLLOWUP &amp;&amp; !viewModel.isMeetingViewGroupShown) 
    || (viewModel.prediction.intent == PredictionIntentType.MEETING &amp;&amp; viewModel.isMeetingViewGroupShown) 
        ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE }" />
```

Ultimately, I just want it to look something like:

```
<LinearLayout android:visibility="@{ viewModel.someViewVisibility }" />
```

I'm using `Java` and `viewModel.prediction` is of type `LiveData<Prediction>` and `viewmodel.isMeetingViewGroupShown` is of type `LiveData<Boolean>` if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should have all your logic in code files not in xml. So what you need is a boolean in your code file that looks something like this.

```
val visible = prediction.intent == PredictionIntentType.MEETING_FOLLOWUP 
    || (prediction.intent == PredictionIntentType.FOLLOWUP && !isMeetingViewGroupShown) 
    || (prediction.intent == PredictionIntentType.MEETING && isMeetingViewGroupShown
```

In your code file also add this method.

```
@BindingAdapter("visible")
fun bindVisible(linearLayout: LinearLayout, visible: Boolean) {
   if(visible){
      linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }else{
      linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
   }
}
```

In your xml add this to your linear layout

```
app:visible="@{viewModel.visible}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Ultimately, I just want it to look something like:

```
<LinearLayout android:visibility="@{ viewModel.someViewVisibility }" />
```

So do exactly that:

ViewModel:

```
val someViewVisibility: Int
    @Bindable get() {
        return if (prediction.intent == PredictionIntentType.MEETING_FOLLOWUP || (prediction.intent == PredictionIntentType.FOLLOWUP && !isMeetingViewGroupShown) || (prediction.intent == PredictionIntentType.MEETING && isMeetingViewGroupShown)) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
```

With the property defined in your viewmodel, your simplified logic will work. Plus, now you can write a unit test for `someViewVisibility` and prove it works. :)

Hope that helps!